# what it means when javascript console shows a circle with #2

Tags: javascript

I just wonder what it means when javascript console shows a circle with `#2`.

[image: in the second line]

Comment: No. of times the same thing is logged.

Comment: That the thing being outputted appeared two times.

Comment: When the result is same as the previous it will update the last result with the number. Here `1` repeats two times

Comment: It means the same message was logged `2` times **successively**.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the output is the same `n` number of times.